# How can I convert the format of my dataframe into a new transposed format in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I would like to convert my dataframe, df1, to the format shown in df2. How can I do this in an efficient manner without hard-coding & while using R libraries?

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 5, 3, 4),
  B = c(5, 9, 4, 7),
  C = c(6, 8, 9, 10),
  D = c(3, 4, 8, 3),
  E = c(7, 2, 5, 5),
  F = c(4, 1, 1, 9)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  attribute_1 =  c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  attribute_2 =  c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  attribute_3 =  c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  attribute_4 =  c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  attribute_5 =  c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  attribute_6 =  c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  attribute_7 =  c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  attribute_8 =  c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  attribute_9 =  c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  attribute_10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
)
##       value:    1  5  6  3  7  4  5  9  8  4  2  1  3  4  9  8  5  1  4  7 10  3  5  9
##     df1 row:    1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  4
```

Comment: what's the logic behind it? Please add more description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```r
df3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, prod(dim(df1)), max(df1)))
df3[cbind(1:nrow(df3), c(t(df1)))] <- 1
```

`df3` is what you want. You can transform the above code into a one-liner:

```r
df3 <- `[<-`(as.data.frame(matrix(0, nr <- prod(dim(df1)), max(df1))),
             cbind(1:nr, c(t(df1))), value = 1)
```

---

###### Check

```r
all.equal(df2, df3, check.attributes = FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 |>
  pivot_longer(everything()) |>
  mutate(rid = row_number()) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, 
              values_fn = ~ 1, 
              names_glue = "attribute_{.name}", 
              names_sort = TRUE, 
              values_fill = 0) |>
  select(-c(name, rid))

# A tibble: 24 × 10
   attribute_1 attribute_2 attribute_3 attribute_4 attribute_5 attribute_6 attribute_7 attribute_8 attribute_9 attribute_10
         <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
 1           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0            0
 2           0           0           0           0           1           0           0           0           0            0
 3           0           0           0           0           0           1           0           0           0            0
 4           0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0            0
 5           0           0           0           0           0           0           1           0           0            0
 6           0           0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0            0
 7           0           0           0           0           1           0           0           0           0            0
 8           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           1            0
 9           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           1           0            0
10           0           0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0            0
# ℹ 14 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `diag` to generate the 0 and 1 diagonal matrix first, then subsetting the rows as required.

```
v <- c(t(df1))
data.frame(diag(max(v))[v,])
```

Checks out:

```
all(data.frame(diag(max(v))[v,]) == df2)
#[1] TRUE
```